# why does it say unused argument for radius = unit(0.1, "snpc")

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I am trying to create a graph with rounded corners, but when I put in the parameter radius =unit(0.1, "snpc") or radius = 0.1, both return 'unused argument (radius = unit(0.1, "snpc")) or (radius = 0.1)' respectively. How can I create rounded corners without this error?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(grid)

read.csv("/Users/benjamincohn/Desktop/R studio/vaccination_percentages.csv") -> un

un %>%
  arrange(Uninsured) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Life.Expectancy.at.Birth..years., x = Uninsured, color = Location)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2, 18, by = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(70, 81, by = 1)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = 'black') +
  ggtitle("Uninsured (%) vs. Life Expectancy at Birth (years) by State (2023)") +
  labs(y = "Life Expectancy at Birth (years)", x = "Uninsured (%)") +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 1, linetype = "solid"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue"),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "deepskyblue3"),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "deepskyblue3", radius = unit(0.1, "snpc")))
```

Comment: See [`?element_rect`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/element.html) that it does not have an argument `radius=`. Do you mean `lineend`?

Comment: or perhaps `ggchickley::geom_rrect`? https://albert-rapp.de/posts/ggplot2-tips/11_rounded_rectangles/11_rounded_rectangles.html

Comment: I also tried roundrectGrob(x=un$x, y=un$y, width=un$width, height=un$height,
                                          r=unit(0.1, "snpc"),
                                          just=un$just, name=un$name, gp=un$gp, vp=un$vp))

but that just returned 'x' and 'units' must have3 length >0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe "base" `ggplot2` has rounded corner rectangles primitives available for themes (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/element.html), but some related packages like `ggfun` do:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = gear)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.background = ggfun::element_roundrect(fill = "gray80"))
```

[image]